# Two-linkage under the force and friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

I need to find friction force in this configuration. Book says that $F_{fr}=\mu P.$ but i think that force $P$ is distributes evenly between hinge (A) and sliding block (B), so friction must be $1/2 \mu P.$ What is the right answer? Thanks.

[image: hinged two linkage under the force]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct! If you use the equilibrium equation for moments about point C, it becomes clear that $N$ must be $\frac{1}{2}P$. (Provided that either the system is light (no mass) or moving slowly (no acceleration), such that equations of equilibrium are valid)